# la busqueda no localiza resultados con los tags a buscar

Tags: python, scraping

Muy buenas,

estoy intentado raspar de forma muy inicial una busqueda en booking para obtener "nombre de hotel" sin éxito en esta web (reducida con bitly, pero en mi código está entera):

https://bit.ly/3pC915C

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

for item in soup.find_all("div", {"data-testid":"title"}):
    print(item.text)
```

este código no produce resultados, alguien me podría ayudar indicando porque no localiza ningún resultado? Muchas gracias.

Comment: No produce resultados por que no hay ningún `div` con la etiqueta `data-testid` y con valor `title`. ¿Qué es lo que deseas obtener?

Comment: https://ibb.co/FbxNntH me gustaría localizar el nombre del hotel y el precio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El servidor no te está devolviendo el mismo contenido al enviar la petición con `requests` porque no le estás enviando los headers mínimos para que interprete que es un navegador quien la envía.

Haz lo siguiente:

```
# Establece un user_agent válido, por ejemplo:
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

# Inicia la sesión y manda la petición con esos headers
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Por otro lado, te recomiendo utilizar html5lib en lugar de lxml. Te quitará bastantes dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Genial!! muchas gracias!! efectivamente faltaba el header, ya funciona!!